# Socialite installation error Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have installed socialite before but haven't experienced this type of error. All of a sudden this error pops up.

What is the problem that caused these errors?

```
c:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-projects\chats>composer require laravel/socialite
Using version ^2.0 for laravel/socialite
./composer.json has been created
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravel/socialite v2.0.0 requires league/oauth1-client ~1.0 -> satisfiable

 by league/oauth1-client[1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.1.0, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.3.0, 1.4.0,
 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.6.0, 1.6.1]
    - laravel/socialite v2.0.3 requires league/oauth1-client ~1.0 -> satisfiable
    - laravel/socialite v2.0.7 requires league/oauth1-client ~1.0 -> satisfiable
 by league/oauth1-client[1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.1.0, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.3.0, 1.4.0,
 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.6.0, 1.6.1].
    - league/oauth1-client 1.0.0 requires guzzle/guzzle 3.* -> satisfiable by gu

    - league/oauth1-client 1.0.1 requires guzzle/guzzle 3.* -> satisfiable by gu
zzle/guzzle[v3.0.0, v3.0.1, v3.0.2, v3.0.3, v3.0.4, v3.0.5, v3.0.6, v3.0.7, v3.1
.0, v3.1.1, v3.1.2, v3.2.0, v3.3.0, v3.3.1, v3.4.0, v3.4.1, v3.4.2, v3.4.3, v3.5
.0, v3.6.0, v3.7.0, v3.7.1, v3.7.2, v3.7.3, v3.7.4, v3.8.0, v3.8.1, v3.9.0, v3.9
.1, v3.9.2, v3.9.3].
    - league/oauth1-client 1.5.1 requires guzzle/guzzle 3.* -> satisfiable by gu
zzle/guzzle[v3.0.0, v3.0.1, v3.0.2, v3.0.3, v3.0.4, v3.0.5, v3.0.6, v3.0.7, v3.1
.0, v3.1.1, v3.1.2, v3.2.0, v3.3.0, v3.3.1, v3.4.0, v3.4.1, v3.4.2, v3.4.3, v3.5
.0, v3.6.0, v3.7.0, v3.7.1, v3.7.2, v3.7.3, v3.7.4, v3.8.0, v3.8.1, v3.9.0, v3.9
.1, v3.9.2, v3.9.3].
    - guzzle/guzzle v3.9.3 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension cu
rl is missing from your system.
    - guzzle/guzzle v3.3.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension cu
socialite[v2.0.0, v2.0.1, v2.0.10, v2.0.11, v2.0.12, v2.0.13, v2.0.14, v2.0.15,
v2.0.16, v2.0.17, v2.0.2, v2.0.3, v2.0.4, v2.0.5, v2.0.6, v2.0.7, v2.0.8, v2.0.9
].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini files:
    - C:\xampp\php\php.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PH
P in CLI mode.

Installation failed, deleting ./composer.json.
```

I have removed many repeating errors with different version since the error code was very big.

Comment: Maybe `the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.` could help you.

Comment: code block on main error message

Answer (score 0):

Run `composer install` or `composer update` first. Then try running `composer require laravel/socialite`.

And you have not installed `curl`, install it first.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by enabling the curl in Php.ini file and install socialite as usual and it worked